# How to get the data for your firebase storage items with the `listAll()` method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I know the documentation shows how to list items like this:

```
     listRef.listAll()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                // All the prefixes under listRef.
                // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
            }

            for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                // All the items under listRef.
            }
        }
    })
```

...but how can I get my data out of `item`?  For example, the image uri or metadata.

```
public class Wallpaper {
private String wallpaperName;
private Uri imageUri;


public Wallpaper(String wallpaperName, Uri imageUri) {
    this.wallpaperName = wallpaperName;
    this.imageUri = imageUri;
}

public Wallpaper() {
}

public String getWallpaperName() {
    return wallpaperName;
}

public void setWallpaperName(String wallpaperName) {
    this.wallpaperName = wallpaperName;
}

public Uri getImageUri() {
    return imageUri;
}

public void setImageUri(Uri imageUri) {
    this.imageUri = imageUri;
}
}





public class ShowWallpapers extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

private List<Wallpaper> wallpaperList;
private StorageReference storageReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_wallpapers);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("wallpapers");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    wallpaperList = new ArrayList<>();


    storageReference.listAll()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                    for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                   // i want to set-up my Wallpaper object here and add it to my list
                  // but how can i do that


                    }
                    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ShowWallpapers.this,
                            wallpaperList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                }


            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Console view of my storage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V94Ld.png

Comment: @kam1234 can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

There is [documentation for how to get the download url](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) from a `StorageReference`.  You might also want to review the [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html) documentation generally, since basically anything you'd want to do while listing references should be there :)

In this case, once you are in the success handler for the `listAll()`, start launching tasks to get the download URL (or metadata, using [`getMetadata()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getMetadata()) and a similar approach) from the storage reference.

Something like:

```java
        storageReference.listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                        for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                            item.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    // Do whatever you need here.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "downloadUrl:" + uri.toString());
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    // Handle any errors
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The above, of course, doesn't descend into any prefixes at the reference location (via `getPrefixes()`), it just lists the blobs that are directly available at that reference.